# Load resp. unload Plugin or MenuItem using the TinyMCE API

Tags: javascript, api, plugins, tinymce-4

I am using [TinyMCE 4.0.x, API4](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:index) for a project at work. I have some simple custom plugins like:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('simplePlugin', function(editor, url) {
    editor.addButton('simplePluginButton', { 
        text: 'Simple Example', 
        icon: false, 
        onclick: function() { alert('Do something...'); } });

    editor.addMenuItem('simplePluginMenuItem', { 
        text: 'Simple Example', 
        context: 'tools', 
        onclick: function() { alert('Do something...'); } });
});
```

I want to *load* resp. *unload* the **Plugin-MenuItem** and the **Plugin-Button** (or the Plugin itself!) on the fly using the **TinyMCE API** and the button resp. item resp. plugin name (in my case *simplePluginMenuItem* and *simplePluginButton* or *simplePlugin*).

The problem i am facing is that i can't reach/find the Plugin OR the MenuItem / Toolbar-Button using the [API](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:index)!

I tried different ways with no success! For example:

- i can get and modify the list of the plugins using `tinymce.activeEditor.plugins`, but then how do i reload the editor using the API?
- [the `tinymce.ui` namespace](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:namespace.tinymce.ui) has a `MenuItem` class, that has a [`remove` method](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:method.tinymce.ui.MenuItem.remove) - how do i find the MenuItem through the API? When i call `tinymce.activeEditor.editorManager.ui.Menu` i am getting the class and not the current menu instance! Is there a way to retrieve the current menu instance using the API?
- the [editor instance](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:class.tinymce.Editor) has a lot of properties, but none of them is for the menu or the toolbar.

Am i missing something? Is there a way at all using the API to retrieve the `MenuItem` or the `ToolbarButton` or could the API be used only for creating new editor items resp. components?

Something like this **pseudocode**:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.getActiveMenu.findMenuItem('simplePluginMenuItem').remove();
```

I found this [old SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856310/how-to-dynamically-load-unload-a-tinymce-plugin), but at the time (year 2009) the question was asked the API Version 4.0.x was not yet released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution that i found, would be to give the toolbar button and the menu item of the custom plugin, unique id of the containing div element:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('simplePlugin', function(editor, url) {
    editor.addButton('simplePluginButton', { 
        id  : 'simplePluginButton001',
        text: 'Simple Example', 
        icon: false, 
        onclick: function() { alert('Do something...'); } });

    editor.addMenuItem('simplePluginMenuItem', {
        id  : 'simplePluginMenuItem001',    
        text: 'Simple Example', 
        context: 'tools', 
        onclick: function() { alert('Do something...'); } });
});
```

Now the generated HTML code inside the TinyMCE editor looks like this:

```
<div    id="simplePluginButton001"
        role="button" 
        class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-first mce-last" 
        tabindex="-1" 
        aria-labelledby="simplePluginButton001">
            <button 
                role="presentation" 
                type="button" 
                tabindex="-1">
                    Simple Example
            </button>
</div>
```

and the div element containers could be retrieved and manipulated directly (for example using jQuery):

```
var pluginToolbarButton = $("#simplePluginButton001");
pluginToolbarButton.hide();
//pluginToolbarButton.show();
//pluginToolbarButton.remove();
```

This works just fine for my case - i can build lists of menu item resp. toolbar button id's, that should be made invisible resp. visible.

Nevertheless i wish i could have used the API for such operations - IMO it is more elegant and it *seems right*.